# Aligning four 'nested' circles along their bottom edges in R

Tags: r, charts, geometry, visualization, bubble-chart

I am trying to create a visual that nests four circles as so:

[image: nestedcircles]

The size of the circle depends on a ratio/numeric value relative to the largest circle.

I found this post which seems to provide a solution for two aligned circles: [Bubble Chart with bubbles aligned along their bottom edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738172/bubble-chart-with-bubbles-aligned-along-their-bottom-edges)

However, I am a complete newbie to R and not sure how to proceed to achieve the desired four aligned circles.

Sample input data:

```
d <- read.table(text = "circle:x
Circle1:340000
Circle2:5000
Circle3:1100
Circle4:340", header = TRUE, sep = ":")
```

Desired Output of four aligned circles based on input numbers:

[image: nestedcircles]

Comment: What does your data look like? What functions are you trying to use to plot such data? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614158/6851825

Comment: Updated to add representative sample data. I have been working off of the sample code in the linked Stack Overflow question. Thank you.

Comment: Once you have decided the radius, place the center at coordinates (X, Y-R) where (X, Y) is the bottom point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert area to radius, then use *ggforce* to draw circles:

```
library(ggforce)

#convert area to R
d$r <- sqrt(d$x / pi)
d$x0 <- max(d$r) / 2
d$y0 <- d$r

ggplot(d, aes(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, r = r, fill = circle)) +
  geom_circle() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well. 
Is there a way to customize the fill/color of each circle as well?

Comment: @katebeckett Yes, see this post to set your own set of colours manually: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15130497/680068